# Use of Blat with gmail or yahoo without stunnel

Tags: smtp

I am trying to use Blat for the distribution of a report from a machine that is not on the corporate network.  The ISP connection is residential Fios and blocks port 80 and I believe local smtp servers on port 25. I could install STUNNEL to connect to the mail service, but am hoping for an easier solution.  Any recommendations on an email service that does not require stunnel or a better way to automate the email distribution of one report nightly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the [RFC-sanctioned](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2476.html) smtp submit port (587/tcp) is for. All decent carriers accept mail on that port, and I know of no ISPs that block it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Sent-It-Quiet**, but othera should works too.

**Sent-It-Quiet** http://commandlinesendmail.blogspot.it/2011/01/command-line-mail-sending-utility.html#comment-form

**SendEmail** http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/

**MailSend** https://github.com/muquit/mailsend#download-sourcebinary